# If < 10 then 02 not 2 !!! Help C++ (Arduino Library)

Tags: c++, arduino, formatting

I'm trying to edit an arduino library, it's

```
int hour() { // the hour now 
  return hour(now()); 
}
```

I tried

```
int hour() { // the hour now 
  char s[25];
  return sprintf(s,"%02d", hour(now));
}
```

But it's returning annoying results, I don't know how to program in C++, I just need to print a "0" if the number is lower than 10. Thanks, Heitor.

Comment: please spare a comment before down voting anyone.It would help them to improve in future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the annoying results are, but based on what you have shown I'm going to take a punt and say you get a compilation error related to mismatched return type in hour(), or that you are accessing invalid memory.

If you want the hour() function to return a 0-prefixed number, you'll need to change the return type.  However, changing it to char* would see you return a pointer to memory allocated on the stack.  Memory that becomes invalid as soon as you return.

What you'd need to do is to set aside a memory buffer in the code that calls hour(), not in hour() itself.  Then you pass that to hour(), along with the size of the buffer.

Your calling code would look something like this:

```
char s[25];  // 25 still seems excessive, I suggest 3, so you can fit two digits plus zero termination.

hour( s, 25 );
```

and your hour() function would be:

```
void hour( char* pBuffer, size_t size ) {
  snprintf( pBuffer, size, "%02d", hour( now() ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return the result without having to allocate data every time you could use something like this.

Note: This only works for values -99 to 999

```
typedef union
{
    char str[4];
    int i;
} CharInt;

CharInt hour()
{
    CharInt ci = {0};
    sprintf(ci.str,"%02d", hour(now()));
    return ci;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", hour().str);
}
```

Comment: please answer carefully.`hour(now())` is the function.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mentioned your question is vague.But from your title and content I think I might help you.

I think you need to print a `0` infront of every digit (hour) that is less than `10`. that is if hour is 1 then print `01` etc.

If that's what you need then you made a few mistakes in your sketch.First of all you are returning a `char` array from the function not `int`. Then `hour(now())` is required instead of `hour(now)`.

```
char * hour() { // the hour now 
  static char s[25]; //might be 5 is enough and more
  sprintf(s,"%02d", hour(now()));
  return s;
}
```

PS : As the return type is char array if you were storing it to an integer variable at caller , as if say `int hr = hour();`,it wont be possible now.So you need to print it directly as `Serial.println (hour ());`

Comment: @Heitor Badotti was this answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since s is local to the hour() function, when you return it goes out of scope and ceases to exist.  So the processor is free to overwrite that with something else.  When the caller tries to access the array it gets whatever was written over it instead of what it was inside that function.  You should never try to return a pointer to a local variable from a function.